# Python 2.7.6 : Binary Tree implemented as array (Memory Error)

Tags: python, memory, tree, binary-tree

I Have made a binary tree. All I have to do is return the value at the parent node of the given list of a tree of given height. However when I run my program it says it has a memory error at line 7. Can someone help me figure out how to fix it?

Constraints:
Your code will run inside a Python 2.7.6 sandbox.

Standard libraries are supported except for bz2, crypt, fcntl, mmap, pwd, pyexpat, select, signal, termios, thread, time, unicodedata, zipimport, zlib.

Code Below:

```
h = 3
q = [7,3,5,1]
def answer(h, q):
    #Setting up Variables to use later on
    size = (2**h)-1
    tree = []
    vals = []
    final = []
    #Populate Values to be inserted into tree
    #Fill Tree with filler
    for i in range(0,size,1):
        vals.append(i+1) #MemoryError Appears Here
        tree.append(-2)
    #Function used to insert values to tree
    def addVal(i):
        tree[i] = vals.pop(0)
    #PostOrder Insertion
    def postOrder(i):
        if (i*2)+1 > size or (i+1)*2 > size:
            addVal(i)
        else:
            postOrder((i*2)+1)
            postOrder((i+1)*2)
            addVal(i)
    #returns parent node of a given index
    def getParent(i):
        if i == 0 or i > size:
            return -1
        else:
            return (i-1)/2
    #returns value being stored at indexed node
    def getValue(i):
        if i == -1:
            return -1
        else:
            return tree[i]
    #Populate Tree with Values
    postOrder(0)
    #return List composed of the values of the parents of provided list
    for i in range(0, len(q), 1):
        final.append(getValue(getParent(tree.index(q.pop(0)))))
    #return List with Values of Parents
    return final #based on input q and h, this should return [-1,7,6,3]
answer(h,q)
```

Comment: That is not your entire code, it only defines one function. Please give a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) by showing us also the calling code with its data. Please also show the entire traceback for the error. Note that the code you show could not possibly have a memory error in line 7, since that line is just a comment.

Comment: Ok I believe i was able to give a minimal, complete and verifiable code.
Since i'm verifying this on an online compiler, it just asks to code for the function. it takes care of providing h, q on multiple scenarios, and compares the returned list from def answer(h,q).

Comment: Which Python version do you use? It seems to be python 2.x, but your example runs fine at mine with python 2.7

Comment: I edited the question to include more information on the environment, It is a 2.7.6 Sandbox with restricted libraries

Comment: by Python sandbox you mean [pysandbox 1.5.1](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pysandbox/) or something else ?

Comment: it could be i don't really have much information on the sandbox other than that i provided, but if it helps  the submission process is more or less as follows:
1. Code a file named file.py
2. In the file you just code a function with given arguements 
    ex. 
    def answer(h,q):
        #code
        return data
3. once the file is saved you run the file through the compiler where it changes up the h, and q to make sure the code will work correctly through varius scenarios.

Comment: But, as long as your script produces an error, you are run it somehow to find it out. How can anybody help you if he cannot reproduce or confirm your problem ?

Comment: Hadn't you considered it is nothing but 'out of memory' issue ?

Comment: It'd almost definitely an issue in your sandbox. Your code might be correct or not but there's no way that it raises a MemoryError in that line in any sane environment.

Comment: I should have written: "there's no way that it raises a MemoryError in that line in any sane environment with the input you provided". Larger values of `h ` could lead to a `MemoryError`, but that does not mean your code is wrong.